# On button click, decrease an integer value javascript html?

Tags: javascript

Code:

```
function displayImage() {
  var textil = 20;
  if (textil >= 2) {
    textil = textil - 2;
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21); // 0...6
    // array in the canvas image using the random number as the subscript value
    document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
  } else {
    alert("insufficient funds.");
  }
}
```

basically, when the button is clicked, its goes `onclick=displayimage()`, but when it does I want it to go -2 on the current `textil` integer that is 20, and so on when ever I click until it has less than 2, then I want it to say that message.

Now I thought this should work, but it doesn't, can someone help me out with this? thanks in advance, also if possible how can I make it so that it saves that value of `textil` even when the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assign value to `var textil= 20;` in the function. So every time it gets called, it will be set to 20 first. You need to take it out of the function.

Basically your code should look like:

```
var textil = 20;

function displayImage() {
  if (textil >= 2) {
    textil = textil - 2;
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21); // 0...6
    // array in the canvas image using the random number as the subscript value
    document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
  } else {
    alert("insufficient funds.");
  }
}
```

Also, your comment `// 0...6` is not actually right, it should say `0..20`

Comment: **Caveat:** Taking variable outside will make it a global variable. To avoid that, wrap you code inside an IIFE.

Comment: Thank you for the fast help, but i still can keep clicking on the button and buying for infinity, idk why this is happening